# Is there a way to scp between two aws instances from my local computer?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, amazon-efs

I want to make a script to backup my files from the fileserver I have(EFS) to an S3 bucket. I want to run it from my computer and the problem is that I don´t know how to make this connection with a PEM File.

I have found in the internet that i can use a scp command to to what I want.
https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/ssh-and-scp-howto-tips-tricks/

But I have to use my PEM file to connect and I can´t find out where it goes here.

```
scp -r yourusername@yourserver:/home/yourusername/examplefile yourusername2@yourserver2:/home/yourusername2/
```

Comment: scp -i /path/garcia.pem

Comment: use the -i switch

Answer (score 1):

you can use your pem file in the same way like you do use with ssh client with a `-i` switch in your case

```
scp -i <Path To PEM File> -r yourusername@yourserver:/home/yourusername/examplefile yourusername2@yourserver2:/home/yourusername2/
```